# Missing these required gems: mongrel (but installed)

Tags: windows-server-2008, ruby, redmine, gem

i am trying to install new plugins for redmine 1.4.4.
Having copied folder and run **rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production** rake wrote:

```
Missing these required gems:
  mongrel  >= 0

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.370 at C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe
  rubygems 1.8.24 at C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8, C:/Users/adm/.gem/ruby/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

**rake gems:install --trace**:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Mongrel
** Invoke gems:install (first_time)
** Invoke gems:base (first_time)
** Execute gems:base
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Mongrel
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
C:/Ruby187/redmine-1.4.4/config/mongrel.rb:20
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/redmine-1.4.4/config/environment.rb:62
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/tasks/gems.rake:17
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:23
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

**gem list** shows that mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32) is installed.
Everything runs on windows 2008 server x64. Redmine working at mongrel win service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cite from the [install guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall):

> If you need to load any gems that are not required by Redmine core (eg. mongrel, fcgi), create a file named `Gemfile.local` at the root of your redmine directory. It will be loaded automatically when running `bundle install`. Example:

```
# Gemfile.local
gem "mongrel"
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the permissions on the Mongrel gem with a gem that has already been validated.

On a side note: Is there a reason that you're using Ruby1.8.7?  It's fairly old.  Does RedMine require that?

Comment: can you describe how to do this, i am new to ruby world.
1.8.7, cause plugins required redmine 1.4.4, which requires ruby 1.8.7